# Локализация формата чисел, в т.ч. рейтинга

Tags: дефект, статус-воспроизведено, локализация

[Википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C):

> чтобы избежать неоднозначности, для разделителя групп разрядов
>   международные стандарты (ISO, Международное бюро мер и весов, ИЮПАК)
>   рекомендуют всегда использовать пробел (или тонкую шпацию при
>   типографском наборе)

Иначе, для русскоязычного пользователя (а также почти любого неанглоязычного), рейтинги выглядят дробными.

Comment: Угу. А ещё в комментариях надо бы убрать en-dash, отделяющий комментарий от ника автора, и заменить на полагающийся по традиции em-dash — иначе текст с тире смотрится не очень.

Comment: Спасибо за отзыв! Добавил в базу дефектов.